# "retry page load" in content.js file *** website root ***

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm-live-server

I get this message every time my page loads for the first time. It really bugs me and my experience while I try to use console for testing my app. I tried looking for the solutions on google but didn't get them. I don't know if this is some basic issue so in case it is, I would really appreciate any help I get.

[image]

I expect to remove this message from my console using some setting or maybe by entirely fixing it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can click `Content.js` in your log to try and see what is producing the log line.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. Mine was caused by the Wordtune chrome extension. Removed the chrome extension since I don't use it and that fixed the problem.

Try changing the access each chrome extension has until you find the one causing it. You can change this under Extensions > More actions > This can read and change site data.

Comment: In Firefox, extension scripts often have the name of the extension in them. Clicking `content.js` in OPs example would probably also lead to some explanation.

Comment: This worked for me as well, wonder why Wordtune is causing it, anyone knows?

Answer (score 2):

Check your browsers extensions, it is usually caused by the ad-blocker or similar.

Comment: thanks for sharing. I'll try to disable the ad blocker. I should have tried that earlier.

Comment: it didn't solve for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you add **Wordtune** as a Chrome extension, please remove it and try again to reload. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: The only thing this "new" answer does is to repeat what other answers are already saying, including the [a well-received answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75587565/14267427).

Answer (score 0):

Work in Incognito mode where it will never happen, Because there is no extension are available.